# Install TomEE Plus in NetBeans 8.0 for RESTful Services

Tags: netbeans, apache-tomee

I wish to Set-up `RESTful` Services with `TomEE+` and `Maven`.

I am unable to set `TomEE+` as server in all following cases:

1. with/without `Tomcat` (in `NetBeans 8.0`)
2. `SVN` checkout - `TomEE+` couldn't be downloaded. Repeatedly Check-out stops. (in `NetBeans 8.0`)
3. out side `NetBeans` with maven clean install. There is build failure.

Java version on my machine is

> java version "1.8.0_05"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)  `

Maven version

> Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T23:07:52+05:30)
>   Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.1
>   Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
>   Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
>   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows" `

Could you please help for how to Install `TomEE+` in `NetBeans`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded it from http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html. Then unzipped it.

From Netbeans from the "services" window:

- Right click on Servers -> Add Server
- Select Apache Tomcat or TomEE
- Browse to find the install directory (for Server Location), specify a username and password
- Click finish

This worked fine for me

Comment: Thanks Peeskillet, I did try this I am able to get both Tomcat and TomEE but not TomEE+ version 1.6.0.2. I want to use             apache-tomee-1.6.0.2-plus.tar.gz or Zip OR. As this is the latest version and setup

Comment: Many Thanks, Peeskillet. I unzipped fresh download a directory in the path of Apache Maven (C:\) and reinstalled. It did work. Cheers.

Comment: Don't for get the accept (tick the check mark) if this answer helped to solve your propblem

Comment: It did surely. I appreciate Peeskillet. I didn't know I had to tick it.